# IF EXIST outputs true on non-existent file

Tags: if-statement, dos

```
IF EXIST %PROGRAMFILES%\Winamp\paths.ini ( REM do stuff )
```

This file (and the folder) DOESN'T exist but it outputs true.

The script is on "K:\" and eventually got started with another file (%1) which as far as i know changes the start directory.

I have no clue why this doesn't work.

Also i tried to navigate to %PROGRAMFILES% and check the existance of \Winamp\ but for some reason it stays at it's home directory (or the one of %1).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably need quotes around the path, because `%PROGRAMFILES%` is going to expand to `C:\Program Files`

```
IF EXIST "%PROGRAM%FILES%\Winamp\paths.ini%"
```

e.g. Without quotes, note how it shows "file not found" **TWICE**:

```
C:\Users\marc>dir %PROGRAMFILES%
 Volume in drive C is Windows7_OS
 Volume Serial Number is 0E31-0E35

 Directory of C:\

File Not Found

 Directory of C:\Users\marc

File Not Found
```

because it was interpreted as

```
dir C:\Program Files
```

which executes as

```
dir C:\Program
dir Files
```

With quotes, it works:

```
C:\Users\marc>dir "%PROGRAMFILES%"
 Volume in drive C is Windows7_OS
 Volume Serial Number is 0E31-0E35

 Directory of C:\Program Files

18/07/2014  04:02 PM    <DIR>          .
18/07/2014  04:02 PM    <DIR>          ..
```

Comment: "\Winamp\paths.ini was unexpected at this time"
EDIT: i had another %PROGRAMFILES% at a different place which made this error but the cmd crashed right away so i didn't know it was that. anyway everything works fine now, thank you very much :)